# how to sort and limit inside document mongodb in php

Tags: php, mongodb

i have the array here.

http://pastebin.com/i5ZUQNm6

and this from php result.

```
$result1 = $mo->find(
  array(
    'username' => 'BLABLA',
    'stream' => array('$exists' => true)
  )
);  
foreach ($result1 as $obj) {
  print_r($obj);
}
```

how i sort the [stream] child and limit it to 1 result? and how to find [id_stream] child?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To limit, to a single document
use `limit(1)`:

> $result1 = $mo->find(   array(
>       'username' => 'BLABLA',
>       'stream' => array('$exists' => true)   ) )->limit(1);

or 
`findOne`

> $result1 = $mo->findOne(   array(
>       'username' => 'BLABLA',
>       'stream' => array('$exists' => true)   ) );

---

And to sort the child.
You need to also add at the end `->sort(array("stream.time" => -1));`
I've seen the pastebin, and I guess you want to order by date.

---

Final code:

```
 $result1 = $mo->findOne(   array(
     'username' => 'BLABLA',
     'stream' => array('$exists' => true)))->sort(array("stream.time" => -1));;
```

From what I know for limiting to a single value of the array <strike>you need a loop</strike>
you need to add (inside the find, just after the main array): `find(.... , array('streams' => array('$slice' => 1)));`

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.sort.php) and [limit](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.limit.php) should work - the code in slownage's answer looks like it may be what you need.